# pandas dataframe to spark dataframe conversion issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark

**Below is my code**
df1 = full_df1.loc[:,full_df1.columns.drop(['Buckets', 'NCT ID','Source','Right values (for reference)'])]
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df1)

```
spark_df.show(2)
```

am using python 3.7.4 and pyspark 3.2.1 version.

All the lines are executed perfectly but the error comes from spark_df.head(2)  line I don't understand where I have done wrong, Much appreciated it if someone helps me.

**But, am getting below error**

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o573.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 9.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 33) (DESKTOP-CDOCCRL executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:182)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:498)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:501)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:135)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:174)
... 29 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2303)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2252)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2251)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2251)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1124)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1124)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1124)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2490)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2432)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2421)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:902)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2196)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2217)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2236)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:472)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:425)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectToPython$1(Dataset.scala:3532)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3700)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3698)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3529)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:182)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:498)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:501)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:135)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:174)
... 29 more

Comment: **Job aborted due to stage failure** -- in my experience, this is generally due to system running out of memory. also, why use `.head()`? pyspark's `.head()` is different from pandas' `.head()`. I think you needed `.show(2)`.

Comment: Thank you, i have solved it as it required some configurations from spark. in my case, have added: "spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled":"true",
    "spark.driver.memory":"1g"   and installed pyarrow library.